# Исчезновение "быть" и замена его на нулевую связку

Tags: грамматика, историческая-грамматика

Почему в современном русском языке в настоящем времени между подлежащим и сказуемым опускается глагол-связка"быть"?Есть несколько случаев, когда "быть" все же присутствует.Например:"У меня есть кошка" или "Это и есть я".Но в первом случае "есть" близко к" существует","имеется", а во втором предложении на появление "есть" влияет частица "и", благодаря чему усиливается утверждение.Но я имею в виду те случаи, в которых "есть", скорее, ближе к слову" являться"."Например, почему говорят:"Москва-столица России", а не "Москва есть столица России"?Для выражения будущего или прошлого времени можно переделать предложение в "Москва будет столицей России" и "Москва была столицей России".Но  когда-то "быть" присутствовало и даже изменялось по лицам и в настоящем времени.Когда "быть" перестало изменяться по родам в настоящем, что спровоцировало исчезновение "быть" и когда оно заменилось на нулевую связку?

Comment: Просто для сведения, _Maria_: в современном русском языке между предложениями всегда имеется пробел. _Москва — столица России._ (Предложение пишется с тире.)